# how can i group employeeId and then group by paidDate in aggregate mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

this my collection data collection

```
{
"_id" : "001-000001",
"employeeId" : "001-001",   
"paidAmount" : 30,
"paidDate" : ISODate("2017-08-23T14:36:14.410+07:00")
},
{
"_id" : "001-000004",   
"employeeId" : "001-001",   
"paidAmount" : 10,
"paidDate" : ISODate("2017-08-23T06:45:29.497+07:00"),  
},
{
"_id" : "001-000005",   
"employeeId" : "001-001",   
"paidAmount" : 15,
"paidDate" : ISODate("2017-08-01T06:45:29.497+07:00"),  
},
{
"_id" : "001-000002",
"employeeId" : "001-002",   
"paidAmount" : 15,
"paidDate" : ISODate("2017-08-01T12:49:08.724+07:00")   
},
{
"_id" : "001-000003",   
"employeeId" : "001-002",   
"paidAmount" : 15,
"paidDate" : ISODate("2017-08-01T06:45:29.497+07:00"),  
},
```

I want to get result like this Please help me

```
{
"_id" : "001-004",
"paidAmount" : 45,  
"employeeId" : "001-001",
"item" : [
    [
        {
            "paidDate" : ISODate("2017-08-23T14:36:14.410+07:00")
            "paidAmount" : 30
        },
        {
            "paidDate" : ISODate("2017-08-01T06:45:29.497+07:00"),  
            "paidAmount" : 15
        },

    ]
  ]
},
{
"_id" : "001-004",
"paidAmount" : 30,  
"employeeId" : "001-002",
"item" : [
    [
        {
            "paidDate" : ISODate("2017-08-01T12:49:08.724+07:00")
            "paidAmount" : 30
        }       
    ]
  ]
},
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: i can group employeeId but when i group by paidDate it work wrong data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"employeeId":"$employeeId","paidDate":"$paidDate"},
    "paidAmount":{"$sum":"$paidAmount"}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"employeeId":"$_id.employeeId"},
    "paidAmount":{"$sum":"$paidAmount"},
    "item":{"$push":{"paidDate":"$_id.paidDate","paidAmount":"$paidAmount"}}
  }},
  {"$project":{
    "_id":0,
    "paidAmount":1,
    "employeeId":"$_id",
    "item":1
  }}
])
```

Comment: when i convert paidDate to String before and then group by paidDate that i convert this paidDate it reduce one day i dont khnow why

Comment: Can you please create a separate question ? I will be happy to answer there.

Comment: why are you converting the paidDate to string ? what is your goal ?

Comment: yes because i want group paidDate also if i do not covert it can not group by paidDate

Comment: what is your version ? If 3.6 you can include the timezone.Something like `saleDateStr: {
            $dateToString: {
                format: "%d-%m-%Y",
                date: "$saleDate",
                timezone:"Asia/Kolkata"
            }
        },`

Comment: my mongo version 3.4

Answer (score 0):

May be if you want to publish composite collection you might want to look at [meteor-publish-composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite) plugin. which allows you to publish composite collection. but it only works on server.